# Player is not looking at correct direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

My Enemy/Bot is facing the wrong direction as shown in the attached screenshot 1. Basically what I want is that Enemy/Bot gun should directly face the player, not enemy/Bot himself.

> Note: The white line in the image is representing Aim direction which
> is correct.

Here is my Code:

```
Vector3 targetPosition = kbcrd.playerToEngage.thirdPersonPlayerModel.shootTarget.position;
targetPosition .y = 0;

Vector3 botPosition = pb.thirdPersonPlayerModel.gunDirection.position;
botPosition.y = 0;

Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - botPosition);

//pb is Bot which is holding transform and other scripts.
pb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, kbcrd.lookingInputSmooth);
```

What I Get from the above code is this: (Screenshot # 1)
[image]

What I want is this: (Screenshot # 2)
[image]

Gun and player Orientation:
[image]

Gun position And Player position at Aim Animation State.
[image][image]

Any help is appreciated. I know its simple problem but I struggling now. :(

Comment: Is your bots gun aligned with its `transform.forward` axis?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am adding reference image.

Comment: Well this is the case for the not animated/rigged model ... is it the case also for the animated state?

Comment: Both player and Bot are animated.

Comment: Yes but how do the local forward axis of the enemy object look like while it is the aiming state? Does it still match with the guns direction? How do you draw the white line? Maybe you can insert a `Debug.DrawLine(botPosition, targetPosition - botPosition, Color.red);` which should match with the desired direction

Comment: I reupdated my question and added new screenshots. I am drawing that line using Debug.DrawLine.

Comment: Yeah you see? The gun isn't pointing in the bot's forward direction! .. That is where your offset is coming from ... if you rotate the bot to look towards the player object the gun is pointing further to the left ... You would either have to take this offset into account and additional rotate the player ... or make sure that in your rig the gun points in the forward direction so you'ld have to adjust your animations to rotate the players body when it is aiming ..  As hotfix the gun should point the same direction as your players chest maybe, you don't really aim like that though ^^

Comment: Exactly I am sure of it that's why I added that gun position so that bot rotate a little further but it didn't work up to expectation. Would you mind if you can tell me that how can I find that offset angle between bot and gun and then add up to the final rotation?
And thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your added Screenshots the gun's direction does not match with the bot's forward axis (blue vector).

You could add this difference to your target rotation like e.g.

```
var targetPosition = kbcrd.playerToEngage.thirdPersonPlayerModel.shootTarget.position;
targetPosition.y = 0f;

var botPosition = pb.thirdPersonPlayerModel.gunDirection.position;
botPosition.y = 0f;

var gunForward = gunDirection.forward;
gunForward.y = 0f;

var botForward = pb.transform.forward;
botForward.y = 0f;

// Get the offset between the bot's and the gun's forward vectors
var gunBotOffset = Vector3.SignedAngle(gunForward, botForward, Vector3.up);
// Get a rotation to rotate back from the gun to the player direction
var gunToBotRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(gunBotOffset, Vector3.up);

// Add the back rotation to the target rotation
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - botPosition) * gunToBotRotation;

pb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(pb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, kbcrd.lookingInputSmooth);
```

One problem left though is that still the Gun model doesn't even match the `gunDirection`'s forward vector so there will still be an offset left!

---

[image]

Comment: Uhhh. Thanks a Lot, it Solved the issue. God, I wish If I was good at math like you. :)